# how to attach a qr code to Promotion pictures in c#

Tags: c#, .net, image, qr-code

please please please~

1. I can use QrCode.Net to generate code img(code.png) base some url;
2. I have a company promotion picture(promotion.png)
3. I want a attach code.png to promotion.png;

result will be like

[result demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Box8l.png)

Answer (score 2):

maybe my question is a little .... no one give me answer;

but after searching, I find this help me, maybe help others

```
 /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="promotionImgPath"></param>
    /// <param name="codeImgPath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static System.Drawing.Image CombinImage(string promotionImgPath, string codeImgPath)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image promotionImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(promotionImgPath);     //promotion Img
        System.Drawing.Image code = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(codeImgPath);        // code Img
        System.Drawing.Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(promotionImg);

        float codeWidth = 175;
        float codeHeight = 162;
        //in order to make code img to center;
        float xPosition =(promotionImg.Width / 2) - (codeWidth / 2);
        float yPosition = 14;

        g.DrawImage(code, xPosition, yPosition, codeHeight, 162);
        GC.Collect();
        return promotionImg;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imageIn"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageIn.Save(ms, imageIn.RawFormat);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```